# SQL statement to remove part of an URL on column

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a `videos` table with a column `URL` with many different URL types

```
https://google.com/questions/ask?963
https://google.com/embed/ask
https://google.com/top/123.html
https://video.net/embed-ask?963
https://video.net/embed-123.html
https://video.net/top?123.html
```

I need to delete part of a specific URL (delete embed-)
from

```
https://video.net/embed-75mdabvgl3do.html
```

to

```
https://video.net/75mdabvgl3do.html
```

I have tray this SQL but return an empty result (0 rows affected)

```
UPDATE `videos` SET url = REPLACE(url, '%video.net/embed-%', '%video.net/%') WHERE `url` LIKE '%video.net/embed-%';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
UPDATE videos
SET url = REPLACE(url, 'video.net/embed-', 'video.net/')
WHERE url LIKE '%video.net/embed-%';
```

This hopefully would be specific enough of a replacement.  If not, we could consider using regular expressions (available if using MySQL 8+).

Comment: Perfect solution